# Assign infinity to float

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to initialize a float to value infinity, and without using INFINITY macro.

```
float f[] = {
            0b01111111100000000000000000000000, // 0x7f800000
            0x7f800000 -1,
            0x7f800000 -2,
            0x7f800000 -64,
            0x7f800000 -65
        };
```

Printed:

```
2139095040.000000
2139095040.000000
2139095040.000000
2139095040.000000
2139094912.000000
```

Why isn't the first data infinity (like `1 / 0.0`) and the others don't change until the last data?

0x7f7fffff should be the biggest value that a float can be and trying [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 0x7f80000 is considered infinity.

Comment: The values on the array will be *converted* to their floating point equivalents, the same way what happens when you do e.g. `float a = 5;`

Comment: You'd have to reinterpret the binary representation as float. I do not know a portable way for that, but in practice a union might work in most cases: `union { unsigned int i; float f; } test;` Set test.i and read test.f. Or just memcpy an int onto a float.

Comment: The printed values other than the last are all the same because type `float` has less precision (but greater range) than does type `int`.  The conversion to `float` loses precision, so that the first four `int` values all convert to the same `float` value, whereas the last `int` is enough different to convert to a different `float`.

Comment: Then the "problem" is that data loses precision. @Ctx using union it gives inf. With union does the assignment never lose precision?

Comment: @SimoneBonato You mix up things here. Assume, you have a number, 0x7f800000. The binary representation of this number in integer format is: 7f 80 00 00. This number _also_ has a binary representation as a float, which is something completely different. And the conversion between these binary formats takes place, when you _cast_ the integer to float (which is done implicitly, when assigning it to a float variable). The union does not change the binary representation, but allows you, to interpret the same representation as float or as int.

Comment: Use `1.0f/0.0f` instead.

Comment: @chux I tried that in MSVC as initialisation - it would not compile.

Comment: @chux What is the difference from `1.0/0.0`?

Comment: @Simone Bonato `1.0f/0.0f` is `float`.  `1.0/0.0` is `double`.  Same "value".

Comment: BTW: Why not use `INFINITY`?

Comment: @chux that works, but with compiler warnings only.

Comment: @Weather Vane what warning (double to float?).  Then could use `((float) (FLT_MAX*2.0))`.

Comment: @chux *warning C4056: overflow in floating-point constant arithmetic*. The earlier error was *error C2124: divide or mod by zero*

Comment: @Ctx Is `0b01111111100000000000000000000000` the binary representation as a float of infinity?

Comment: `0b01111111100000000000000000000000` is `2139095040`  If that  is assigned to a `float`, it will have the same value.

Comment: @SimoneBonato According to IEEE754 and 32-bit, yes

Comment: @chux is that so? And what is 0b11111111100000000000000000000000 then? May be positive or negative, it's a matter of interpretation. Or even -inf when it's the binary representation of a float in IEEE754

Comment: The `float` value `+infinity` in binary is `01111111100000000000000000000000`, `-infinity` is `11111111100000000000000000000000`. The exponent `11111111` indicates infinity, plus the leading sign bit.

Comment: @Ctx So the reason why if I assign `0b01111111100000000000000000000000` to a float, it isn't "inf" is that float has lost precision?

Comment: @Ctx  OP is using a compiler which allows code with binary constants like `0b11111111100000000000000000000000`.  This 32-bit value would have the value of 4286578688.

Comment: You can't just assign a binary value to a `float` like that. It's a **binary dump**.

Comment: I haven't reached that warning (I use gcc), do you know any pages about binary dump?

Comment: I meant it is a bit by bit description of the `float` - not it's actual value. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: So a part of `*(int*)&f` aren't others methods to assign to a float infinite value? (except using constants)

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `INFINITY` macro? That's what it's for.

Comment: Integer constants, whether hexadecimal like `0xff800000` or binary like `0b11111111100000000000000000000000` (when supported as a compiler-specific extension) do not indicate representations. They indicate *values*. `0xff800000` has the value 4286578688, and is of the first of types `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, or `unsigned long int`, that can hold its value. If you assign it to a floating-point type, the value is converted, yielding an approximation of `4286578688.0`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thanks for your explanation. I don't want to use that macro because I want to do experience directly with IEEE 754...

Comment: C doesn't guarantee that floating-point uses an IEEE 754 representation. You should update your question to make it clear that you're specifically talking about IEEE 754 infinity. You should also explain why you don't want to use the `INFINITY` macro; your reasons would probably also apply to the other obvious solutions, such as using `HUGE_VAL`.

Comment: In my question I had linked to a page about IEEE 754, however I thought C normally used IEEE 754. However: yes, I like alternative ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of your problem is notations:

- `0x7f800000`
- `0b01111111100000000000000000000000`

This notations related to `int` type and when you assigning `int` to `float` it means `implicit conversion` from `int` to `float`. In this case both of your numbers is `2139095040` in decimal and it will be conerted to `float` type.

To avoid this problem you may assign value in exact bit positions of 4 bytes. Here a couple of examples.

```
float f;
*(int*)&f = 0x7f800000;
```

Or you can use unions

```
union u_fi {
    float f;
    int   i;
} fi;
fi.i = 0x7f800000;
```

But be careful when use this 2 solutions. It won't work safely when `int` is more than 4 bytes in first case and won't work at all when `int` is `big-endian`. So this solutions are platform dependent and I recommend to use macro like it shown below.

Another solution to your problem is to use very large number wich converts to `float` as `inf`. For this you can use macro as in `<math.h>`

```
#define _HUGE_ENUF  1e+300
#define INFINITY   ((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))
float f = INFINITY;
```

Comment: Beware of endianness, `float` does not necessarily have the same as `int`. And `int` may not be the same size as `float`. Suggest using `uint32_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes. You are right. It should be something like `uint32_t`, but I prefer to use _native_ types which do not require additional headers. In MSVC it will be `__int32`
Anyway if `int` will be more than 4 bytes it won't broke conversion and `float` will be `inf`

Comment: `*(int*)&f` exactly what does it mean?

Comment: MSVC 15.0 defines `uint32_t` in `stdint.h` which is a standard type, but `__int32` is not.

Comment: @SimoneBonato, this expresion consists of 3 parts:
`&f` - operation takes address of `f` variable.
Then `(int*)` _casts_ this address to **pointer to int**.
And last one * is operator for pointers which gives to write value in address which pointer is containing.
So we represent memory of our `float` variable as `int` and assign value like you assume it to assign in your question. Not by casting to int.

Comment: @SimoneBonato `*(int*)&f` takes the address of `float f`, so it is a pointer to `float`, then casts that to a pointer to `int`, and writes the `int` value `0x7f800000` to that address. That is *not* the value of the infinite `float` but the *same bit pattern* that the `float` uses to represent infinity. It's a shortcut way of using the `union` method, but I believe it's frowned on to cast pointers from one type to another.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I think additional headers isn't necessary. Especially given the fact that the size of `int` does not matter.

Comment: It does matter when `int` is big-endian.

Comment: @WeatherVane, if so this solution isn't cross-platform. For cross-platform solution author should use INFINITY macro from `<math.h>` header.

Comment: *"I'm trying to **initialize** a float to value infinity, and without using INFINITY macro."*

Comment: `*(int*)&f` violates the strict aliasing rule and should not be used.

Comment: @M.M points out, you should use valid method for type-punning (e.g. `memcpy` or type unions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro HUGE_VAL. Or, if you prefer, you can initialize a dummy variable to zero, and divide by that variable (so you won't get a compilation error).

Comment: `HUGE_VALF` is of type `float`, `HUGE_VAL` of type `double`, and `HUGE_VALL` of type `long double`.

Comment: Well, I supposed that he couldn't use INFINITY because he is not working with C99 but maybe I was mistaken. Of course it would be easier to help if we knew why he can't use INFINITY.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using IEEE754 (which your question implies), you can give a result that would overflow. `float` can only represent values up to `3.4028235f38`, so we could use

```
float x = 1e20f*1e20f;
```

Depending on your system/compiler you may need to specify flags (e.g. `c99` or `c11` will work) so that `x` is explicitly casted to `float` and not stored as higher intermediate precision.